# Is the terminal text meant to be "?SYNTAX ERROR" in "Square Root"?

Tags: vvvvvv

In the level "Square Root" of VVVVVV, I activated the terminal, and the following text appeared: "?SYNTAX ERROR". This is vastly different from the terminal text in the rest of the game and seems to indicate an actual syntax error bug in this version of VVVVVV. I'm playing the Steam version on Windows 8.

For reference, I've included an image of the terminal text above, and an image of the map below (the white box in the bottom left corner of the map is the location of "Square Root".)

[image: Activating the terminal in "Square Root"]

[image: "Square Root" on the map]

Is this supposed to be the terminal text, and if not, what is the terminal text supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, while many terminals in this game can give you hints or background information, there are also terminals that simply display an error, as is the case here. So yes, this is supposed to be the text for this particular terminal.